# jQuery - display answers with delay

Tags: jquery

I've created some interactive labs for a course I'm teaching, question/answer style. The student sees a "question" like "Use the cp command to copy file1 to file2." When they click it, the answer displays below: `cp file1 file2`

But the students are lazy, they're just going through and clicking the answers, typing the commands verbatim, and not learning anything. I changed the code so that each click hides all other answers, and added a 10s delay before displaying. But the problem now is that there's very little feedback to a click. I would like to perhaps display the next element, but without its contents, or perhaps a loading gif?

Here's my current (relevant) code:

```
.answer {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333;
  color: #999;
  font-family: monospace; 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".step").next().hide();
  $("li").click(function(){
      $(".answer").hide();
      $(this).next().delay(10000).show(0);
      $("li").show();
    });
});

<li class="step">Use the <code>cp</code> command to copy file1 to file2.</li>
   <div class="answer">
   $ <span class="cmd">cp file1 file2</span>
   </div>
```

What's the best way to get the div block to display, but put a delay (or a loading gif) on the contents?

(Also, I'm a total jQuery noob, so if I've done something ridiculous, please point it out.)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share html code

Comment: what element are you trying to put the delay on?

Comment: Just hide the answer span as well and add a second delay that shows it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a loading gif by inserting:
      `$(this).after('<img src="/ajax-loader.gif" />');`
     `$(this).next().delay(1000).hide(0);`
after the initial delay. Sorry for the screwed up comment formatting, indenting code is not working for some reason. :/

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code and your HTML is also not in pro

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).next().hide().delay(10000).show(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could animate the visibility css property of the answer container.

See the [jQuery .animate() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). It let's you to play not only with the duration of the animation but also with the **easing** function to be used.

That is, the function which defines the speed variation of the animation across the time of its duration.

jQuery only provides two easing functions by default, but there is more on [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and, if I'm not wrong, you can implement your own ones (I never did too).

This way, you could begin with a little visibility and low or none increment while a time, and complete it's visualization only in the last seconds of the whole delay.